# Canadian tourist visa after Paris attack

Tags: visas, canada, event-based-effects, egyptian-citizens

I'm an Egyptian Muslim pharmacist living in the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia. I want to apply for a Canadian tourist visa.

I'm just wondering if there are any new restrictions or procedures after the November 2015 Paris attacks?

I have valid USA and Schengen visas, and three past Schengen visas as well as visas from China and Turkey before.

Comment: What changes do you think there have been, and why do you think these changes apply to you?

Comment: I just heard rumors that schengen is going to be suspended and french borders will be closed so i'd like to ask if there will be changes in north america ( usa and canada ) too or not .

Comment: Hi @Mostafa, welcome to Travel.SE. I edited your post to add some relevant tags and to make it more clear; please feel free to edit or rollback if I have misrepresented anything.

Comment: We already a question about these rumors: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58807/travelling-in-out-france-after-the-attacks-of-november-2015 Basically, the only way in which the Schengen agreement has been “suspended” is that the police now stands most of the time on the *internal* borders with Belgium, Luxembourg, Germany, Switzerland, etc. Beyond that, all borders are opened, external borders operate normally and visa policy hasn't changed.

Comment: @Relaxed he's asking about Canada though

Comment: Many thanks for prompt responses ! Really helpful ..

Comment: @blackbird57 Yes but I thought it was useful to know that the rumors weren't true, even with respect to France itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such restrictions currently in effect for Egyptian citizens. You can see [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-all.asp) that you're just required to have a visitor visa, and this page [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) shows no warnings when checking for Egypt. The Canadian [embassy](http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/egypt-egypte/index.aspx?lang=eng) to Egypt currently has no publications or warnings about restrictions

> **Egypt**
>   Carry proper travel documents and identification
>
> You must also make sure that you:
>
> Carry proper travel documents and identification for yourself and any
>   children travelling with you. Demonstrate to an immigration officer
>   that you satisfy all other requirements to enter Canada. If you do not
>   meet all the requirements, you may not be allowed to enter. To find
>   out what else you may need to know before you come to Canada, see
>   Arriving in Canada.

The only restrictions I found were [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/apply-who.asp) and [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/inadmissibility/index.asp) and don't apply to you (unreliable passports and inadmissibility criteria)

Comment: @Mostafa anytime :)