# Can I travel to Paris with Schengen visa after Paris attacks?

Tags: schengen, paris

I have Schengen Visa which have been issued by Italy. I would like to know that if I can travel to Paris after Paris Attacks? It is appreciated if someone give me any information about this case. because I've heard that french government suspend schengen visas policy. I have bought flight tickets from Milan to Paris for next week and I do not know that if i can take that flight.

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58807/travelling-in-out-france-after-the-attacks-of-november-2015

Comment: Yes, you can travel to Paris. The government has suspended certain aspects of the Schengen system, which they can do under the rules of the system itself.  That is, they haven't in the least withdrawn from the Schengen legal framework.  Schengen visas remain valid and French entry requirements are unchanged.  People applying for entry may receive more thorough scrutiny than they otherwise would have, to ensure that they meet the requirements, and they will be more likely to be scrutinized at internal borders.  The borders, however, are not "closed," as many have been saying.